# CloudFormation EC2 Windows Script

Tags: json, windows, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I'm just starting with CloudFormation. I'm trying to create 2 Windows EC2 instances with custom properties (VPCs, Security Groups, Subnet and tags. ), but I don't know how to set this up, I started with the standard AWS template and modified it but it fails.

```
{
  "cxawsprodnew01": {
    "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
    "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
    "Tags": [{ "tag": "" }],
    "Properties": {
      "ImageId": {
        "Fn::FindInMap": ["WindowsRegionMap", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" }, "AMI"]
      },
      "InstanceType": "r4.large",
      "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior": "stop",
      "DisableApiTermination": "true",
      "VPCId": { "Type": "AWS::EC2::VPC::Id", "Ref": "vpc-9b34b5fd" },
      "SubnetId": { "Ref": "VpcSubnet1" },
      "SGUtilized": {
        "Type": "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup::Id",
        "Ref": "ProdOctopusSG"
      },
      "BlockDeviceMappings": {
        "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
        "Ebs": {
          "VolumeType": "standard",
          "DeleteOnTermination": "false",
          "VolumeSize": "50"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I modify this to allow me to add the properties that I need, no I have to set them first as parameters to invoke them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can declare the properties in the properties section and reference it.

```
{
  "Properties": { 
    "VpcId": { 
      "Type": "WS::EC2::VPC::Id"
      } 
  },
  "Resources":
    {
      "cxawsprodnew01":
        {
          "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "DeletionPolicy": "Retain",
          "Tags": [{ "" }],
          "Properties":
            {
              ...
              "VPCId": { "Ref": "VpcId" },
              ....
            },
        },
    },
}
```